# Enable Sql Dependency in Application Insights on Azure Functions with EF Core

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, ef-core-3.1

I have an Azure Function v3 application which uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.5`. I am not able to enable SQL Dependency tracking. Struggling with it 1 day already.

To isolate the issue, I have created a standalone AzureFunction without EF. Instead of EF I was using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.0.19269.1` which is also used by EF.
Here goes the function:

```cs
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var ids = "";
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
            {
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 10 Id FROM table";
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ids += reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ",";
                    }

                    ids = ids.Substring(0, ids.Length - 1);
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult("Ids:" + ids);
        }
    }
```

References for app

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="1.0.19269.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
```

After deploying the application to Azure(without EF), SQL dependencies are tracked as expected.

After adding a reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to the project and nothing else is changed, the tracking stops working. After removing the reference tracking is working again.
Updating the references to the latest version does not help either.

Do you have any idea why is this happening? Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4` they introduced an issue which causes this behavior. Downgrading to 3.1.3 solves it.

**UPDATE**:
After I have opened a bug on github, [they pointed me towards an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/2032) with  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and EventSource which are related to this one.

Comment: we are facing similar issue. We are using 3.1.7 which is the latest version. Do you see any issues with the code initialization? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498368/azure-sql-dependency-based-on-ef-core-3-1-7-is-not-appearing-in-application-ma

Comment: Not working for me. I am using EFCore 3.1.3 as mentioned, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 1.1.3,  and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.10.0